# Question on applying glmer to average population

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model

Suppose we have data on contractors who build houses and we are trying to model the overall risk of construction problems, which is coded as a 0-1 variable. My features include things like cost, location, materials used, etc. To this end, I have a generalized linear model with logistic link and contractors as random effects:

$y=\mathbf{X}\beta+\mathbf{Z}\gamma+\epsilon.$

After fitting the model in R with glmer from the lme4 package, I would like to consider how a given contractor would perform on an *average* house job.  This is where my question arises.

I see two ways of approaching this. The first way, would be to take my data set and average all house parameters to give me an average house $\mathbf{x}$ which I could plug in for each contractor. The second option would be to apply each contractor to every single house in my data set and then average the resulting probability of problems. The issue is that these methods are rather different primarily because the link function is non-linear. However, I'm guessing that the average house arises in the near-linear region of the link function (where it rises sharply). What would be the advantages of doing either method? I'm also open to other suggestions for measuring this kind of "average" risk for a contractor.

Are there accepted names for the above measures?

Answer (score 1):

For method 1, you are looking at the probability of having problems for a given contractor for ONE typical house. That means the house itself is considered average in terms of the features you used. This is good indication for people that want to make houses similar to the "typical" house.

For method 2, you are looking at the average probability of having problems for a given contractor over all the houses; this gives a good look at the contractor's average performance on all types of houses. It's a better indication of overall performance than method 1 but it depends on your sample of houses. If your sample contains a lot of say, 3-floor houses and a particular contractor specializes in 3-floor houses, then their performance might look better than a contractor that specializes in bungalows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you happen to know if there's a standard name for these methods when it comes to GLMs?

Comment: That I'm not sure.